# Express server with React front end routing without server side rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, server-side-rendering

This is my express server setting

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


require('./api/accounts/signin')(app);
....

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
mongoose.connection.on('error', function() {
    console.info('Error: Could not connect to MongoDB. Did you forget to run `mongod`?');
});

app.set('super-secret', process.env.APP_SECRET)

module.exports = app;
```

Now when i start my application at localhost:3000/ it works fine with all the routes working but when i try to go on localhost:3000/login or some other route directly i get a `Cannot GET /login` error...

I dont want to use server side rendering with a react middleware (which i have used before) just now so is there anyway to make it work?

```
app.get('/*/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join( __dirname, 'public/index.html'))
})



<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>Doyouthink?</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="js/common.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/polyfill.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to match all routes and serve them the base html page which includes your bundle. React Router will then examine and URL and render the appropriate components.

```
app.get("/", handleRender);
app.get("*", handleRender);

function handleRender(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
}
```

Comment: What will be handleRender here? isnt this a middleware for react in a sense aka server side rendering?

Comment: Sorry, edited. It just serves up your index html file.

Comment: Alright thank you so much... Also while we are at it, is it necessary (at some point in life) to plug in server side rendering in your single page application for making it SEO friendly and stuff like that or Im good to go without it?

Comment: It is mostly useful for SEO and people with slow connections. I'm fairly certain Google's bot will execute JavaScript, but other spiders won't necessarily correctly crawl your site. It isn't terribly difficult to setup, but I haven't read anything that says you must use it.

Comment: Hi i have run into a problem with this solution and im getting the html page as a response object from one of my API now which was working just fine before and sometimes the API are returning bad request. Is there something we missed?

Comment: Okay i just used my API require statement before the sendFile statement and now it works as expected..

Comment: Hi i have a different bug that showed up... any link with a single `/` like `/login` is working when i load it directly but when i load anything with double `/` like `localhost:3000/account/wall` i get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` why is that happening?

Comment: I tried doing what i mentioned in my question edit.. but thats not working

Comment: What is the name of the file that is failing to load? Do you have a relative path in your `index.html`? For example if you have `<script src='bundle.js'></script>` when you try to load that from `example.com/account/wall` it will resolve that to `example.com/account/bundle.js` which does not exist. If you make sure that all of your static files are absolute, this should not be an issue.

Comment: I have updated my question with index.html file that loads the js on refresh. any link with a single `/` is loading the script but advance link '/account/wall' returns error (apparently cant find the script file?)... my public folder has a js folder which contains all the webpack bundles `public/js/*.bundle.js` with .html file in `public/index.html`

Comment: Add a `/` to the beginning of all of your script paths to make them absolute. I.e.  `js/common.bundle.js` should be `/js/common.bundle.js`.